# AlertDialog with single button?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I really want to make an AlertDialog with single button, can someone guide me with this. Thanks!

Comment: any clues? language, platform, web/desktop

Comment: I want to creat an Alert Dialog in android

Comment: Which language and or platform are you working on? `AlertDialog` is possibly from Android, is that what you are working on?

Comment: the question is tagged with android, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
.setTitle("Error")
.setMessage("Please fill out the entire form")
.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
})
.create()
.show()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // do something interesting.
    }
});
// other code to customize the dialog
Dialog d = builder.create();
```